# GCP Project Internal Error Retrieving Logs

Tags: logging, gcloud, google-cloud-logging

It seems like all the logs are not loading for my GCP project anymore (it was just working yesterday, so nothing has changed). The Legacy Logs Viewer under Logging gets stuck on "loading" for a long time before I get this error: `There was an error retrieving logs: Internal error encountered.`. I've also tried reading the logs through the command line using `gcloud logging read`, and I get a similar error: `ERROR: (gcloud.logging.read) INTERNAL: Internal error encountered.`.

Any ideas on how to fix this or reset the logging somehow?

(UPDATE): Oddly enough, running `kubectl logs` works... but still no luck on seeing it on the actual GCP logging console UI

Answer (score 1):

If it was working yesterday and suddenly stopped, It is related to an ongoing issue on Cloud logging as per the [GCP Status dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/). Below is what is shown on the top of the page:

> Cloud Logging delays on log ingestion in the us-central1 region and
> 25% of the global region. Projects in us-central1 may experience
> failures running queries.

You can also check on the page if the issue has been fixed or not. Since the Engineering team is already aware of the issue, it should be fixed soon enough.

Comment: Yup, you're right. Started working again for me the next day. Thank you!